# Are there any open source C#-based non-blocking, event-based web server like Tornado?

Tags: c#, open-source, webserver, comet, tornado

I want to build a comet-based application and would like it to be able to sustain up to 1000 concurrent connections. As I understand, Tornado has the advantage of not spawning one thread per request thus allowing it to handle thousands of long poll requests easily.

Comment: Do you need the service to run on a desktop machine? IIS comes with Windows Server, and should be able to handle this load trivially.

Comment: Does IIS spawn a thread for each HTTP request? As I understand, this is the reason why Tornado is more suitable for long poll system than Apache. I am assuming IIS does the same thing.

Comment: IIS does not span a thread for each HTTP request, heavens no. It does use IO completion ports.

Comment: @AlexanderN, it doesn't spawn a new thread, but it does dedicate a worker thread to each request from a limited worker thread pool.  Unless the handler for the request specifically implements `IHttpAsyncHandler` then that thread us utilized for the entire processing of the request, including waiting on a long-polling trigger event.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think [Manos de Mono](http://jacksonh.tumblr.com/post/1159500924/manos-de-mono-the-manifesto) is what you are looking for.  It is still pretty early, but looks promising.

Answer (score 3):

To process long polling requests with ASP.NET / IIS you want to implement a custom HTTP handler and implement `IHttpAsyncHandler`.  This allows you to begin processing the request, utilizing an ASP.NET worker thread, and then return the thread to the thread pool while waiting on an event to trigger a response.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227433.aspx

> Asynchronous HTTP handlers enable you to start an external process (such as a method call to a remote server) while the handler continues processing. The handler can continue without waiting for the external process to finish.

ASP.NET MVC also provides an `AsyncController` to simplify implementing asynchronous request processing within this framework.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598.aspx

Answer (score 1):

IS it http://webserver.codeplex.com/ , what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

you can try Mongrel2 with dot net bindings. It is very fast language agnostic web server. It works via zeroMQ.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a straight port of Tornado to C#. It's not 100% yet, but getting there.

https://github.com/swax/Tornado.Net